# Как оформить XSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Всем привет!
Сейчас делаю отчет, который выводится в excel.

```
// Создаем новую книгу
    Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

    /* STYLES */
    XSSFColor baseBackgroungColor = new XSSFColor(Color.decode("#db6060"));
    XSSFCellStyle titleStyleRED = (XSSFCellStyle) wb.createCellStyle();
    titleStyleRED.setFillForegroundColor(baseBackgroungColor);
    titleStyleRED.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```

и у меня такие вопросы: 
1. как установить цвет текста. 
2. и как сделать выделение ячейки по контуру. ну чтобы получилась в итоге сетка.

спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
XSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);
style.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
style.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
style.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);

Font font = workbook.createFont();
font.setColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
style.setFont(font);

...

cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

Comment: да все заработало, спасибо.